# Detect when an Application stops Responding, Kill it and Restart it

Tags: c#, windows

I am developing a high performance App that is causing the main process to seemingly stop responding and crash - from time to time -  due to overload (I get the Close Application Dialog so the App never exits *per se*, just freezes, which is annoying)

I welcome any clean way to pro grammatically detect when the App is frozen, so I can use a BAT (or else) to automatically Kill the process and Restart.

Of course, this is a temporary fix while auditing the App, but it comes very handy in the meanwhile.

**TieBreaker :** BTW, Is there a way to override windows' Exception Screen and just quit the App ???
This is mostly annoying feature most of the time.

**EDIT :**
FOR GOD'S SAKE : the app **IS** freaking freezing, **THOUGH** every single task run in BG Workers and threads !!! And I specified that in comments. Come'on, I am not that dumb. Just that your app runs BG workers does not imply it never freezes ! And As I said, please JUST answer my question, I am not looking for lessons on how to design my App, that I am already working on and I know what has to be done. As specified MANY times, I just need a fix on the server in the meantime.
Thank you.

Comment: Why not use background threads instead? Sounds like a weird solution. What is your app doing what it is frozen?

Comment: Band-aid workarounds have a nasty habit of becoming permanent kludges :-)

Comment: can you post an example of the code where you think or know where it's blowing up..?

Comment: @paxdiablo That is so true. For almost everything, not only software so I tend to never do band-aid workaround. Instead I leave it like shit and fix it big time when I can

Comment: @OskarKjellin : I AM using Background threads (A LOT) and the problem is that I am still having few bugs that causes some of them not to end every now and then. Still auditing. But I need a solution in the meanwhile

Comment: @paxdiablo: Com' on, it's almost midnight here, and I'm still stuck at the office. And I'm not getting paid for the extra hours :-) 
So I NEED a workaround NOW for tonight. I need to sleep dude :-P

Comment: @OskarKjellin : If I "leave it like shit" I will just get fired :-) And I know nobody is going to give me extra time to fix this in the short term.

Comment: What is the technology, Winform/WPF/Silverlight?

Comment: Send the app a windows message periodically.  If you don't receive a reply, consider it dead - that's basically what Windows does to determine whether to bring up the Close Application Box.

Answer (score 16):

I'll say it if noone else will :) Make a separate forms app that does-

```
Process[] prs = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process pr in prs)
{
    if (!pr.Responding) 
    {
        try
        {
            pr.Kill();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}

//then to restart-
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"C:\yourapp.exe"
    }
};
process.Start();
```

Obviously oversimplified.

Comment: Simple and Elegant. No, not elegant, but effective - and that's what We need.

Answer (score 2):

We handle this in a service by having the main service exe be little more than a shell that launches the child threads.

The child threads are then responsible for reporting back to the parent thread whenever they can to record the last date/time they were "seen".

On a regular interval, the service app checks the list of child processes and, if one hasn't been seen for a predetermined period of time (i.e. 2 minutes), but did not report that it had closed down, the parent process will first try to join the thread and shut it down gracefully (usually fails) and then, if that didn't work, aborts the thread.

We have used this approach successfully for many years, starting when an OCR service that we were running would hang constantly due to bugs in the OCR software.

Comment: Well that is smart. I did not specify this, but this is exactly how it is done on my app now. But I was still wanting to track a total freeze of the app (i.e "really" and "directly" detect it went off the hood in some way). But I don't know if this is possible

Comment: Killing a thread can cause all sorts of problems, including hanging the application, e.g., because the killed thread held the heap lock.  (I wonder if this was the OPs original problem?!)

Answer (score 1):

Move all CPU instensive tasks off of the GUI and invoke back to the gui to report any statuses.

The main app **should never freeze**. I wrote an app that generated over 500 threads (all at once) and managed them as they asynchronously (.net 2) processed multiple database calls. I believe you need to systematically move all processes to a thread safe situation and remove any direct GUI calls.

ADDENDUM How did I run 500+ threads:

1. Usage of smart locks done from the beginning on all shared data locations. See my blog articles
   [Smart Resource Locking in C# .Net for Thread Safe Code](http://omegacoder.com/?p=120)
   [C# MultiThreading Using ThreadPool, Anonymous Delegates and Locks](http://omegacoder.com/?p=262)
2. Interface created which specified an action operation with data, error status as a properties.
3. Threading base class created (for classes in #4 and #5) which created, started and cleaned up thread opertions. *No business logic, just a method of handling threading in one location.*
4. Class created based on interface in #2 and also derived from step #3. Class via the interface was required to get data and place data (thread safe via localized lock) and report its status. **Class also designed to give up thread cycle if no work done to be done via thread.Sleep(0)** instead of busy waiting.
5. Manager class created (which ran on its own thread and derived from #3).It launched 1-N #4 classes to do work. Each of those instances was placed into a working list.
6. Manager class simply browsed the working list for instances which reported their work was done if it was done it moved the instance to the done work. Manager class also kept records of the status (thread safe via locks) to exposed properties (as well as any reported errors by the children instances). Manager gave up thread cycle after each run and slept for 250 milleseconds before starting again.
7. GUI thread had working timers which dealt with getting specific status from the manager. They would extract the data from the manager's properties and invoke back the GUI to target a control (gridview) which reported all statuses and errors.

By doing that, I was able to achieve individual threads doing specific work and if a process ran into a problem it reported it, or it reported success or failure. Those messages bubbled up to the manager which bubbled up to the timers which bubbled up to the GUI. The gui handled no business logic except to start the mananager and timers.

---

I get that this doesn't help your situation right now and I *feel your pain*. But until you are able to seperate out the business logic from the GUI and handle error situations in the threads (background workers) and bubble them up to the GUI, you will still have this frustration with the current code.

If something is locking that is a sign that business logic is too tightly coupled with GUI operation and that has to be divorced before you will get the performance you want from the GUI.

HTH

Comment: How did you keep the main thread aware of the their statuses? So many threads reporting even every so often would still cause some work to be done in the gui thread.

Comment: @Eddie Paz : Thank you, at least I feel understood.

Comment: @MikaJacobi You have work to do, here is what I did, but maybe just doing smart thread resource locking could help? HTH (See addedum as to how I did it and links) GL

Comment: @OmegaMan. Ok. Thank you for taking time to write a detailed and constructive answer now :) I am indeed auditing my App. It happens that it is VERY complex, because I have nested threads at many layers and I have hundreds of them (It i a high performance stock market listener). The problem is that on the proto evertything went fine, but on pre-prod threads sometimes go rogue. And it is very hard to tell why. I get null exception and out of sync workers and such bizarre behaviours from time to time. I even dropped the GUI for a Text interface. I will check your list while auditing.

Comment: @OmegaMan: But I needed first something to fix temporarily the situation. I had to deliver and I was left no other short term choice. Thanx again.

Comment: @MikaJacobi I fully understand you needing to get something out the door. I see you are in Paris. I had the opportunity to travaillé for Cegetel in La Défense in Paris back in the 90's. One of the best contracts of my life. GL with the code, you will get it working.